# Rails: Why "format" (regex) validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following validation of product's price:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    PRICE_REGEX = /^([1-9]\d{0,5}|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$/
    validates :price, :presence => true, :format => PRICE_REGEX
    ...
end
```

It supposed to allow prices from `0` to `999999.99`.

However, if I enter `hello`, the validation passes, and `0.00` is saved in the database.

The `:presence` validation works fine, though.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The price column is a float, and so Rails will automatically convert the string "hello" to float, as per `"hello".to_f # => 0.0`. This is then converted back to the string `"0.0"`, which obviously matches the regular expression.

In general, it's a bad idea to use regular expressions on non-string columns. Instead, use `validates_numericality_of`. If you wanted the same restriction as with the regex, do it like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0, :less_than => 1000000
end
```

Not only is it safer, but it's easier to read and follow as well. Note that it'll automatically reject the price if blank as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but every description I saw from validates uses :format in this way:

```
validates :price, :presence => true, :format => { :with => PRICE_REGEX }
```

Maybe the problem is there