# How to prevent Rails from changing the content of the input field when validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a decimal `price` field in my product model, and a simple validation:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates_numericality_of :price
  ...
end
```

If I type by mistake `33.0p`, it says: "Price is not a number" (I agree), and changes the content of the input field from `33.0p` to `33.0`.

So, if I type `33.0p` and press the submit button quickly (thinking that everything is OK), I will get the error message. Then I will look into the input field to check what's wrong. But, there I will see a valid number (`33.0`), and I will ask myself "What's wrong...?".

Is there any way to prevent Rails from changing the input field content when validation fails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use `read_attribute_before_type_cast`, ie `f.text_field(:price, :value => @product.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:price))`.

Comment: This is even better: `:value => @product.price_before_type_cast`. Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is the same as my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467224/rails-why-format-regex-validation-fails); Rails converts the input to a float at some point during the process, and therefore the float value is what shows up.

I haven't tested this, but you can try overriding the value of the text field to be `params[:product][:price]`. In theory, this would look something like:

```
f.text_field(:price, :value => (params[:product] ? params[:product][:price] : @product.price))
```